# scandir or opendir does not work when path contains space in PHP

Tags: php, directory, space

The following functions does not work when there is space in the directory path. For example, in the following path directory name is   'Stack Overflow_files' which contains a space.

```
 $dir = '/home/mamun/workspace/barj/barj/barj/Sequence/Stack Overflow_files';
 $scanned_directory =  array_diff(scandir($dir, 0), array('..', '.'))
```

or

```
$dh  = opendir($dir);
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
         $scanned_directory[] = $filename;
}
```

I can find the solution from the terminal running *ls '$dir'*. but is there any way in php to get the dirctory listing?

Comment: It works for me with space in the name. Are you sure there isn't another issue?

Comment: I don't know. Are you sure it works in linux envernment. The space even gives wrong result when I run terminal command from PHP. like exec("du -hs $path");

Comment: The space does matter for shell commands but not PHP file system functions.

Comment: If I run the following command in terminal, it runs perfectly.      dir /home/mamun/workspace/barj/barj/barj/Sequence/Stack\ Overflow_files/ 2>&1   but if I call it from php                   $out = array();   exec("dir /home/mamun/workspace/barj/barj/barj/Sequence/Stack\ Overflow_files/ 2>&1", $out); it gives permission denied message.

Comment: This is a permissions problem so actually unrelated to the space. You need to make sure that PHP has read access to the directory. The web server (apache) and therefore PHP will usually run as a different user to the local user you use for everyday things. Search for "Linux File Permissions" in your search engine of [choice](http://www.google.com/search?q=linux+file+permissions). If you continue to have problems then ask another question about the permissions.

Comment: yes; you are correct. How can I give you some reputation points? The folder was created by another user that's why apache user hasn't got the permission to open it.

Answer (score 1):

Bro this is the final solution 
$path="/var/www/images";
$dir="folder with space";
$files=scandir("${path}/${dir}");
And bingo

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution

```
 $URL = str_replace("\ ","%20","../pasta1/pasta com espaco/pasta2");<br>
 $arquivos = scandir($URL);

<br>

 echo $arquiovos[0];<br>
 echo $arquiovos[1];<br>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

try escaping the space with a backslash-

```
$dir = '/home/mamun/workspace/barj/barj/barj/Sequence/Stack\ Overflow_files';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$dir = urlencode('/home/mamun/workspace/barj/barj/barj/Sequence/Stack Overflow_files');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try urlencoding. The directory path
May be like

```
         $dir = '/home/mamun/workspace/barj/barj/barj/Sequence/Stack%20Overflow_files';
```

Comment: after urlencoding it looks like    %2Fhome%2Fmamun%2Fworkspace%2Fbarj%2Fbarj%2Fbarj%2FSequence%2FStack+Overflow_files. still it doesn't work.

Comment: try
 str_replace(" ","%20","/home/mamun/workspace/barj/barj/barj/Sequence/Stack Overflow_files");

Comment: still not working. even space makes problem when i get size of a folder from running exec() of php of a shell command. for example,          $command = "du -hs '" . $folderpath."'"; exec($command) it gives wrong  folder size.