# PHP Scandir folder with spaces in its name

Tags: php

I have a file with this name = "File in my computer.pdf";
When I try to scan the folder with the scandir function I get the error: The directory name is invalid.

I've tried to escape the filename with str_replace or with urlencode but I get that scandir can't find the filename.

This is the code:

```
$filename = "/folder/File in my computer.pdf";
scandir($filename);`
```

I've tried:

```
$filename = "/folder/File in my computer.pdf";
$filename = str_replace(" ", "\040", $filename);
scandir($filename);`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scandir or opendir does not work when path contains space in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120342/scandir-or-opendir-does-not-work-when-path-contains-space-in-php)

Comment: Nope, as I said I've already tried with str_replace but I get the same error

Comment: if you used the filename as input of `scandir` the error was expected to be `failed to open dir: Not a directory` and that alone was enough to shed light on the right direction. That compared to `The directory name is invalid.` that doesn't fit very well indeed and sounds invented.